# Is there a way to separate a few seconds from the beginning of an audio file?

Tags: android, audio, notifications, mp3, trim

I want to set up a **30-second** audio file for the **notification sound**

But I have to separate the first 3 seconds or 4 seconds from this song and then adjust.

Is there a way?

Comment: `NotificationChannels` (Oreo+) are permanently bound to a sound resource, so if you wanted multiple sounds, you'd need a `NotificationChannel` for each one.

Comment: sir, I just want my Application trim sound automatically